# StdIn, cmd, ctrl-c, using Stack.java and Evaluate.java in same directory

Tags: cmd, stack, stdin, copy-paste, evaluate

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class Evaluate 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stack<String> ops = new Stack<String>();
        Stack<Double> vals = new Stack<Double>();
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
        {
            String s = StdIn.readString();
            if  (s.equals("("))         ;
            else if     (s.equals("+"))     ops.push(s) ;
            else if     (s.equals("-"))     ops.push(s) ;
            else if     (s.equals("*"))     ops.push(s) ;
            else if     (s.equals("/"))     ops.push(s) ;
            else if     (s.equals("sqrt"))  ops.push(s) ;
            else if     (s.equals(")"))                 
            {
            String op = ops.pop();
            double v = vals.pop();
            if  (ops.equals("+"))       v = vals.pop() + v;
            else if     (ops.equals("-"))   v = vals.pop() - v;
            else if     (ops.equals("*"))   v = vals.pop() * v;
            else if     (op.equals("/"))    v = vals.pop() / v;
            else if     (op.equals("sqrt"))     v = Math.sqrt(v);
            vals.push(v);

            }
            else vals.push(Double.parseDouble(s));
        }
        StdOut.println(vals.pop());
    }
}
```

I am trying to get this program (its straight from the book) to work via command prompt. It will compile, and run. However, when I give it input such as ( 5 + 3 ) and then ctrl-c to exit the program it doesn't give me a result of the computation. Maybe, I have missed something simple, maybe I don't fully understand how ctrl-c is supposed to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a 10-second quickie, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl-z resulted in a result of 3. Assuming that is the last number it received?

Comment: Possibly. I know diddly about Java. Classically, ^C terminates a process whereas ^Z is an EOF (End-Of-File) flag. I believe that ^C was terminating your process, but ^Z was recognised as end-of-input hence reading `stdin` says "that's all" and your `!STDIN.ISEMPTY` would be FALSE (not-isempty because it now **IS** empty). Tracing why it's not performing as you expect on the input data is a matter for a relative Java expert (ie. YOU) - I just solved why ^C acted as it did - abandon the program (hence no output) rather than ^Z - here's the end of input - do your calculations...

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the help and I will try to figure the rest out.

Comment: But - looking at what the code says, while there's input available, push each element. When it stops, pop the last entered and write it. End-of-program. I'd suggest you then actually do some calculations on the stack you've built. That might help.

Comment: Whats bothering me is that this program is copied straight from the book and it should take an arithmetic expression and evaluate it, without me changing anything.